# cap_ios.h is not found

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

apparently, I have download the opencv2.framework from http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/

but after I've download the example project from GSOC 2012
the facedetectvideo project requires opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h in the framework but opencv2.framework doesn't have it.

any suggestion about the latest full framework?

any help would be appreciated.thx

Answer (score 61):

As of now, the header file was moved to a new location. Try this.

```
#import <opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h>
```

Answer (score 12):

From new libraries, you have to use following header

```
#import "opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h"
```

Comment: How does i know... but after googling a lot i find this appropriate answer.

Comment: Perhaps I was getting error for missing `#import "opencv2/highgui/ios.h"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need cap_ios.h.

You only need to `#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` in your prefix.pch file after you drag the "opencv.framework" file into Xcode.

The GSOC opencv code is for some sort of development version.

Comment: well, could u send me the opencv.framework for me?
the svn from the site is no longer exist.. and always refuse connection in the github... please send to romin991@gmail.com .. thx you very much.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.2/opencv2.framework.zip/download ;)

Comment: @romin you can download latest framework from here https://github.com/Fl0p/OpenCV-iOS