# How to build an XCode 6 iOS app that uses OpenCV - Error __cplusplus is not defined

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv

I'm having an issue running an xcode project with OpenCV. I've followed the instructions on this [page](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation) to build the OpenCV framework for iOS. Then I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#opencviosvideoprocessing) to build a test app.

But when I try to build, it looks like __cplusplus is not defined since

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

is not executed.

I can't seem to get my project to compile c++ files that would get this to work. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

I've made sure that my build settings knows of the .pch file, and double checked that the framework was added.

I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1, Xcode 6.1.1, and the type of application I created was Single View Application

**Update**

It looks like it *is* compiling the __cplusplus block. I #define a variable within the #ifdef block, and when I NSLogged it, it showed up. It seems like it just can't find the file for

```
opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h
```

**Update 2**

In addition to @NobodyNada's comment below regarding changing .m file to .mm, I also had to change the import statement from

```
opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h -> opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h.
```

I found this out from @ToyHunter's answer in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797783/cap-ios-h-is-not-found).

Comment: Have you changed your file extensions for implementation files that need OpenCV to `.mm`?

Comment: Just tried it, but still the same problem.

Comment: What was the old name of the file that you changed?  Also, did you try building your project after renaming?

Comment: It was ViewController.m, I changed it to ViewController.mm. Yeah, I cleaned and rebuilt.

Comment: Is `ViewController.mm` the only file that imports OpenCV?

Comment: Yeah, that's the only place.

Comment: @NobodyNada Looks like you were right, when I changed it back to .m my variable no longer showed up. It looks like in addition to changing the file to .mm, OpenCV also changed the location of the cap_ios.h file so in both cases it didn't compile. If you like, you can post your comment as the answer and I'll mark it as the answer to this question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the file extension of all files that import OpenCV to `.mm`.  OpenCV is a C++ API, and changing the extension of a file to `.mm` changes the language used in the file to Objective-C++, which lets you mix C++ and Objective-C.

Comment: I also had a similar problem and had to declare the properties in the .mm file instead of the header.